# How to set time of java.util.Date instance to 00:00:00?

Tags: java, date

I have a variable of the type `java.util.Date`.

How can I set the time part to 00:00:00?

I am not allowed to use an Apache Commons library or JodaTime. The `java.util.Calendar` is probably my only option.

Comment: @AnthonyKong FYI, you can convert [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects to java.util.Date objects ([`toDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate())), and back again. So you can make use of Joda-Time for calculations without disturbing other existing code.

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And other classes from the same API depending on your precise requirements.

Comment: In some time zones dates exist that haven’t got any 00:00:00. You will have to make yourself satisfied with getting the first moment of the day.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To remove time from the `Date` object completely, you could use this:

```
public static Date removeTime(Date date) {    
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
        cal.setTime(date);  
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
        return cal.getTime(); 
    }
```

Pass into the method the `Date` object that you want to modify and it will return a `Date` that has no hours/minutes etc.

If changing the Date object itself isn't required, use `SimpleDateFormat`. Set the format the way you want ie. remove hours/minutes. Then call the format method and pass in the `Date` object you want changed.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(yourDate));
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is probably not clear. I want to, at the end, obtain a date variable which does not carry hour, min and sec.

Comment: @Sionnach773's solution doesn't contain neither hour, nor min or sec. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Sionnach733 Perfect!

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

If you meant midnight in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in an old legacy [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object…

```
java.util.Date.from(
    OffsetDateTime.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
        LocalTime.MIN ,
        ZoneOffset.UTC
    ).toInstant()
)
```

If possible, discard the legacy `Date` portion above and just use the modern [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object…

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
    LocalTime.MIN ,
    ZoneOffset.UTC
).toInstant()
```

If you meant midnight in a [particular time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than UTC…

```
LocalDate.now()
         .atStartOfDay()
```

Better to specify your desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on current default.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
```

## Details

**Caution**: Not every day in every time zone has a time of 00:00:00. Daylight Savings Time can jump to 1 AM, eliminating a midnight.

## java.time

Using java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `.Calendar`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( z );
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z );
```

### Convert to/from legacy classes

You should stick to the modern java.time classes whenever possible. But if you must have have instances of the old legacy classes, you can convert to/from java.time. Look to **new methods added to the old classes**.

```
Calendar myLegacyCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;

Date myLegacyDate = Date.from( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

If you want a `java.util.Date`, which is always in UTC time zone, to have a time-of-day of 00:00:00, use `OffsetDateTime` with the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( localDate , LocalTime.MIN , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
Date myLegacyDate = Date.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. This section left intact as history.

Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3, with a method for this very purpose: [withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29).

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime firstMomentOfToday = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay();

System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "firstMomentOfToday: " + firstMomentOfToday );
```

When run…

```
now: 2013-12-05T23:00:23.785-08:00
firstMomentOfToday: 2013-12-05T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

Comment: The question is specifically looking for a DATE

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna Nope. Reread the Question. The author considered and excluded two 3rd-party libraries. Then  the last sentence suggests using `Calendar` class. So I can safely assume (a) they are open to an alternative, new classes built into Java, and (b) they are simply operating in ignorance, not yet having been informed of the java.tine classes available to them.

Comment: the question is asking to set the time in a java.util.date object isnt it ?

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna I already pointed you to relevant parts of the Question, written in plain text. Furthermore, we have many hundreds of Java Date/Calendar class questions that have now been answered with **java.time classes that directly supplant the legacy classes** as directed by Sun, Oracle, and the JSR community.  There comes a time when the only responsible advice is to abandon your [Yugo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava_Koral) and use the Honda sitting in your driveway. Nevertheless, I did add some verbiage and code example for converting to/from legacy objects.

Comment: thats more to the point then. people get here when trying to look for the answer to the question at hand, not some random answer youre trying to come up with by yourself. Answer what was asked dont answer what was not asked and what you believe is a better question. you got upvoted for the good post now.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 'java.time.LocalDate.atStartOfDay()' can be used too:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Instant inst = date.toInstant();
    LocalDate localDate = inst.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    Instant dayInst = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date day = Date.from(dayInst);
```

Comment: Correct answer. I just want to point out that we normally don't mix the modern java.time classes with the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`. So ideally one would stop once the `Instant` object was obtained. Only convert to `Date` if absolutely necessary such as interacting with some older code not yet updated to java.time.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Sionnach733, to remove time from Date, you can write this function for your DateTimeUtils with clear:

```
public static Date getDateOnly(final Date input) {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(input);
        cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest version courtesy of Ole.V.V

```
import java.time.*;

Instant dInst = LocalDate.of(1980, Month.JANUARY, 8).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
long milli = dInst.toEpochMilli();
```